# Android - Material Design Library: How to use the collapsingToolBar Layout

Tags: android-layout, android-toolbar, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm new to android development and am trying to work with collapsingToolBar in Google's material design library. I am new to this whole collapsing toolbar, but I followed some online tutorials and made an xml according to my needs keeping in mind the advices. I have a main activity with a viewPager containing 5 fragments, now I want that the viewPager should occupy full screen when the user scrolls the activity and the rest of the activity is the collapsing toolbar.

The rest of the activity has two imageViews, a rating bar and some TextViews in it. I'm not sure if all of these are compatible with the collapsing toolbar layout so I'm trying.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhFfl.png) is what I meant to say. This is a screenshot from before I tried to implement the coordinatorLayout and collapsing Toolbar.

[Here](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/zddyP38TgKHsggZuEQXsDlqrO2b6Kc2KipduxciMDRe4BxH7WmBZkaTQK2r0vKSgv6s=h900-rw) is the type of output I want from the app. This example has less tabs in the viewpager but the basic collapsing toolbar layout implementation is the same. Here is the playstore line of the app, just in case: play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kkings.cinematics

Here is the xml of my activity, the current one (having collapsing toolar):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/tvDescAppBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompact.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/tvDescCollapsingToolBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="@color/chocolateBrown"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tvDescTabLayout01"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/black"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/tvBackgroundImage"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="200dp"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/tvImageMain"
                            android:layout_width="120dp"
                            android:layout_height="150dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                            android:foregroundGravity="left" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvDescHeading"
                            android:layout_width="140dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tvBackgroundImage"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvImageMain"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                        <RatingBar
                            android:id="@+id/tvDescRating"
                            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_below="@id/tvBackgroundImage"
                            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:numStars="5"
                            android:stepSize="0.5"
                            android:visibility="visible" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvDescIdTag"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvDescReleaseDate"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescRating"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvDescId"
                            android:text="ID: "
                            android:textColor="#D2D2D2"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvDescId"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@id/tvDescIdTag"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescRating"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                            android:textColor="#D2D2D2"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvDescReleaseDate"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescHeading"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvImageMain"
                            android:textColor="#D6D6D6"
                            android:textSize="13sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescAppBarLayout">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tvDescTabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/tvDescViewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the type of result this activity produces:

> i.stack.imgur.com/hPruf.png

I haven't made any changes in the java. The credits or any other class can't display anything. I suspect that this is due to some clash between recyclerView and nestedScroll View.

So, anyway, I saw that in all the online tutorials, they used a toolbar inside the collapsingToolbarLayout. So I tried doing the same same thing, hereis the new XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/tvDescAppBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompact.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/tvDescCollapsingToolBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="@color/chocolateBrown"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/transparentColor"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tvDescTabLayout01"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/black"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/tvBackgroundImage"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="200dp"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/tvImageMain"
                            android:layout_width="120dp"
                            android:layout_height="150dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                            android:foregroundGravity="left" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvDescHeading"
                            android:layout_width="140dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tvBackgroundImage"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvImageMain"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                        <RatingBar
                            android:id="@+id/tvDescRating"
                            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_below="@id/tvBackgroundImage"
                            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:numStars="5"
                            android:stepSize="0.5"
                            android:visibility="visible" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvDescIdTag"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvDescReleaseDate"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescRating"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvDescId"
                            android:text="ID: "
                            android:textColor="#D2D2D2"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvDescId"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@id/tvDescIdTag"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescRating"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                            android:textColor="#D2D2D2"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvDescReleaseDate"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescHeading"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvImageMain"
                            android:textColor="#D6D6D6"
                            android:textSize="13sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescAppBarLayout">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tvDescTabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/tvDescViewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This toolbar makes everything weird, this is what this looks like:

> i.stack.imgur.com/PfqP9.png

Also, the logcat doesn't show any errors.

I just can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. I have checked all other similar questions on StackOverFlow, none of the solutions have worked so far.

And here is the tutorial I was mentioning:

> www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssh09JbQ3nc

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **The point** was in removing the first `RelativeLayout` which it wasn't
>   necessary & adding the `RelativeLayout` outside of the `Toolbar`.

This should work now:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescAppBarLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/tvDescViewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tvDescAppBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompact.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/tvDescCollapsingToolBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tvDescTabLayout01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tvBackgroundImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_intro" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tvImageMain"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg"
                    android:foregroundGravity="left" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDescHeading"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvBackgroundImage"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvImageMain"
                    android:text="This is theheading"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/tvDescRating"
                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvBackgroundImage"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:stepSize="0.5"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDescIdTag"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvDescReleaseDate"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescRating"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvDescId"
                    android:text="ID: "
                    android:textColor="#D2D2D2"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDescId"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/tvDescIdTag"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescRating"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#D2D2D2"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDescReleaseDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescHeading"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvImageMain"
                    android:textColor="#D6D6D6"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tvDescTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Results:**

[image]